# Trying to insert values to elements generated automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert values to elements which `id`'s are generated automatically:

this code works:

```
<input type="tekst" id="<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
<script>
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value = 1
</script>
```

but I don't want to have a static value of `1`, I'd like to have the value generated automatically so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value =<?php getVotesValue($item->getId());?>
</script>
```

but this wont work,

```
 function getVotesValue($gifId){
    global $db;
    (line 115)$dislikes = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as dislikes FROM gif_dislikes WHERE gif_id='$gifId'"); //line 115

    $resultArray = $dislikes->fetch_assoc();
    $dislikesAmount = $resultArray['dislikes'];
    echo $dislikesAmount;
}
```

Comment: You aren't echoing `getVotesValue(..`. Also you don't need JavaScript for this...

Comment: What does `getVotesValue()` do ? Does it echo anything ?

Comment: Define *won't work*? What does the PHP function `getVotesValue($item->getId());` output?

Comment: updated with the method of getVotesValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't echoing `getVotesValue`, so nothing is assigned to your JavaScript variable.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value =<?php echo getVotesValue($item->getId());?>
</script>
```

However, there's no need for any JavaScript here. Try:

```
<input type="tekst" id="<?php echo $item->getId();?>" value="<?php echo getVotesValue($item->getId());?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work when you echo `getVotesValue()` function unless it already does `echo`.

```
document.getElementById("<?php echo $item->getId();?>").value =<?php echo getVotesValue($item->getId());?>
```